# Take array of strings as property accessor

Tags: javascript, performance

I would like to get a value from an object with accessing it with array of strings.

Static example: Input: `['a','b','c']` Output: `function (t) { t.a.b.c; }`

I would like to make a function that resolves the problem for any array.

```
function (state) {
  let value = state;
  for (let i = 0; i < propNames.length; i++) {
    value = value[propNames[i]];
  }
  return value;
};
```

Other solution is a generator for a function by reducer.

These are working. I would like to know if there is any other faster solutions that I didn't think of.

You can test [here](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/a6jKUFv7WvtBeIKb?open=lib%2Fscript.js) the algorithms. There is a place where your code can be added.

Comment: Seems like both a premature and a micro optimisation. Is there a particular need for this to be "faster"?

Comment: I would recommend looking at the source code for [lodash `get`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#get).  Lodash tends to be absurdly optimized, and since their `get` function does what yours does and a little extra, it would be a good comparison.

Comment: @Bucket Sorry if I was not clear enough. I just want to find a faster solution for this problem.

Comment: @VLAZ I don't have any particular reason.

Comment: @AlexanderNied I will measure the speed of that, too.

Comment: @androbin "I would like to know if there is any other faster solutions." You were clear that you want a faster solution. I asked why. I can think of no practical reason for this to be faster. Any improvement in speed will be negligible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fast way to do it is to iterate over the properties and access the inner objects sequentially, you can do this using [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) or a for loop:

```js
const get = (obj, props) => props.reduce((out, p) => out && out[p] || undefined, obj);

const obj = { a: { b: { c: 5 } } };

console.log(get(obj, ['a', 'b', 'c']));
console.log(get(obj, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']));
```

Or, you could evaluate the expression using `eval()`, however, this is probably the slowest way to do it, **I do not recomment it**:

```js
const get = (obj, props) => {
  try {
    return eval(`obj.${props.join('.')}`);
  } catch {
    return undefined;
  }
}

const obj = { a: { b: { c: 5 } } };

console.log(get(obj, ['a', 'b', 'c']));
console.log(get(obj, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']));
```

Comment: why not just return the value of `out[p]`: `props.reduce((out, p) => out[p], obj)` the assingment makes no sense.

Comment: @Nina Scholz, thanks for the comment, you are totally right

Comment: You also may want to test your object (in case `obj = {a:0}`) `const get = (obj, props) => props.reduce((out, p) => out && out[p] || undefined, obj);`

Comment: This algorithm is great but slower that any that I provided. Eval can work with making a function as a builder. `eval('(obj) => obj.' +propNames.join('.'))`. This is 6 times faster than the solutions that I have given.
The reason is probably that the browser does not need to create more scopes for local variables or stacks for functions.

Comment: *It is good to know you should use it only with compile time constants.*